# SQL Server Select the most recent past date if no future date available

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table structure as below,

```
CREATE TABLE #CustOrder ( CustId INT, OrderDate DATE )

INSERT #CustOrder ( CustId, OrderDate )
VALUES  ( 1, '2016-11-01' ),
        ( 1, '2019-09-01' ),
        ( 2, '2019-07-01' ),
        ( 2, '2019-11-01' ),
        ( 3, '2017-01-01' ),
        ( 4, '2016-12-01' ),
        ( 4, '2017-01-01' )
```

I want to list the customer with their future order dates, if they do not have a future order I want to list their last or most recent order. I have the following query.

```
; WITH LastOrder AS
(
    SELECT 
        CO.CustId, 
        CO.OrderDate, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CO.CustId ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, CO.OrderDate, GETUTCDATE()))) AS RowNum 
    FROM #CustOrder AS CO

)
SELECT LO.CustId, LO.OrderDate
FROM LastOrder AS LO
WHERE LO.RowNum = 1
```

This query gives me the result as,

```
CustId  |   OrderDate
--------+-------------
1       |   2016-11-01
2       |   2019-07-01
3       |   2017-01-01
4       |   2017-01-01
```

However, I need the result as,

```
CustId  |   OrderDate
--------+-------------
1       |   2019-09-01
2       |   2019-07-01
3       |   2017-01-01
4       |   2017-01-01
```

As

1. Customer 1 has a future order on 2019-09-01
2. Customer 2 has two future order but the first one is on 2019-07-01
3. Customer 3 has no more than 1 order, it should just return 2017-01-01
4. Customer 4 has two past orders but the most recent is 2017-01-01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rextester: http://rextester.com/PBKNA95127

```
CREATE TABLE #CustOrder ( CustId INT, OrderDate DATE )

INSERT #CustOrder ( CustId, OrderDate )
VALUES  ( 1, '2016-11-01' ),
        ( 1, '2019-09-01' ),
        ( 2, '2019-07-01' ),
        ( 2, '2019-11-01' ),
        ( 3, '2017-01-01' ),
        ( 4, '2016-12-01' ),
        ( 4, '2017-01-01' )

; WITH LastOrder AS
(
    SELECT 
        CO.CustId, 
        CO.OrderDate, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CO.CustId 
                          ORDER BY case when co.OrderDate > getdate() then 0 else 1 end
                          , abs(DATEDIFF(DAY, getdate(),CO.OrderDate)) asc
                         ) AS RowNum 
    FROM #CustOrder AS CO

)
SELECT LO.CustId, LO.OrderDate
FROM LastOrder AS LO
WHERE LO.RowNum = 1
```

results:

```
+--------+------------+
| CustId | OrderDate  |
+--------+------------+
|      1 | 2019-09-01 |
|      2 | 2019-07-01 |
|      3 | 2017-01-01 |
|      4 | 2017-01-01 |
+--------+------------+
```

Comment: You can have multiple order bys? Little confused how the partition works in this answer.

Comment: @AzizJaved Yes, you can have multiple columns or expressions in the `order by`. The `partition by` resets the row number for each unique set of values for the columns in `partition by`. Take a look here to see what it looks like with the `rownum` and showing all columns: http://rextester.com/HUUN7240

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick response. I think this will work in my current predicament. Much appreciated.

Comment: It'll first put all the future dates first because of the 0. And if there are multiple future dates, the one that is earliest future date will appear first (and therefore shown). If there are no future orders for a given customer, it'll return 1, and then within the multiple past orders, the least negative number will appear first.

Comment: @AzizJaved Correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `MAX` function to check if the latest date is in the future. If so, get the `MIN` date after today using `MIN`. Else get the latest date.

```
SELECT CUSTID,OrderDate 
FROM (SELECT  CustId, 
              OrderDate, 
      CASE WHEN MAX(orderdate) OVER(PARTITION BY CustId) > GETUTCDATE() 
      THEN MIN(case when orderdate >getutcdate() then orderdate end) OVER(PARTITION BY CustId)
      ELSE MAX(orderdate) OVER(PARTITION BY CustId) end as latest_date
      FROM #CustOrder) T 
WHERE latest_date=orderDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Min, Max, UNION approach

```
select custID, MIN(OrderDate)
  from #CustOrder 
  where OrderDate > '2017-02-17'
 group by custID 
union all 
select co1.custID, max(co1.OrderDate)
  from #CustOrder co1
 where not exists ( select 1 
                      from #CustOrder co2 
                     where co2.CustId = co1.CustId 
                       and co2.OrderDate > '2017-02-17' 
                  )
 group by co1.custID
```

Answer (score 0):

Start your ORDER BY with a CASE expression that prefers future over past, and then use the ABS DATEDIFF (like you have now) as the second condition in the ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create another column and use the LAG() window function to grab the last date function and then put a conditional/case statement within the select portion? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx